# How to trigger batch file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, jar

I have a batch file which contains many jar files separated by semicolon :

```
%~d0 
cd %~dp0
java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .;../lib/routines.jar;../lib/accessors-smart-1.1.jar;../lib/advancedPersistentLookupLib-1.0.jar; test_sample_connector.test_connector_0_1.TEST_connector  --context=Default %*
```

When I call this batch in NodeJS I am getting the following error :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

But this batch file works fine if I run in command prompt.

Here is my node js code:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe',['/c','../config/TEST_connector_0.1/TEST_connector/TEST_connector_run.bat']);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: How do you call it ?

Comment: Actually this bat file is auto created one, I didn't replace anything. `%~dp0` is pretty useful in a bat: it is the folder in which the executing bat file resides. I found this in stackoverflow itself.